# What's the etymology of the surname Delvecchio?

Tags: etymology

What's the etymology of the surname Delvecchio?
  I know there's a Plaza Vecchio in Florence.  They can't all be from there :o). 
 The literal translation is not a name I would prefer.

Comment: In Florence you find “Palazzo Vecchio”, which means “old hall”, so it’s not named after somebody. “Plaza” is not an Italian word.

Answer (score 1):

[Del Vecchio:](https://www.cognomix.it/origine-cognome/del+vecchio.php)

> Deriva  da forme patronimiche relative a capostipiti il cui padre era soprannominato Vecchio.
> Tracce di una famiglia Del Vecchio si trova a Firenze fin dal 1200.
> Il cognome Del Vecchio è tipico della zona centro meridionale dell'Italia.
> Delvecchio ha un ceppo in Lombardia tra milanese e bergamasco, uno in Emilia-Romagna tra ravennate, forlivese, riminese e pesarese,  ed uno in Puglia tra foggiano, barese e brindisino.

(It derives from patronymic forms relating to progenitors whose father was nicknamed Vecchio.
Traces of a Del Vecchio family has been in Florence since 1200.
The surname Del Vecchio is typical of the central southern area of ​​Italy.
Delvecchio has a lineage in Lombardy between Milan and Bergamo, one in Emilia-Romagna between Ravenna, Forlì, Rimini and Pesaro, and one in Puglia between Foggia, Bari and Brindisi.)

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer.

Comment: OP, it is clear to you that _vecchio_, by itself, means “old”? So apparently this hypothetic forefather so nicknamed was especially old, or had a son in old age or something.

Comment: @DaG - in Middle Ages growing old (by current standards) was far less common than it is nowadays. So, probably, families  who had old living grandfathers, for instance,  might have been referred to as “Del Vecchio”. That’s the way I understand  it, and it doesn’t appear that incredible.

Comment: I agree perfectly, @Hachi. I was just pointing out to the OP the meaning of the Italian word _vecchio_ in case they don't know it, or else they wouldn't understand what “was nicknamed Vecchio” would entail.